# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\cos n|}{n}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\cos n|}{n}$ diverges.

I knew that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin n|}{n}$ diverges, but it seems the proof for the case of sine cannot be applied to the case of cosine.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I have seen this three times in this website, I answered it one time. You can search my profile for an answer.

Comment: @AhmedHussein: the integral test only works if the function to integrate is monotonically decreasing (to zero), which is not given in this case.